# $_GET['id'] is not receiving id value

Tags: php, url, blogs

I was trying to retrieve `$id` in *category.php* value from the another page *sidebar.php*. but I couldn't receive the value of `id`.

Sending script in *sidebar.php*

```
<a href = "category.php? id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo   $row['title'];?></a>
```

receiving script in *category.php*

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

`$id` is not having any value but false.

I tried my best to resolve this issue but couldn't. can anyone help me out with solution?

Comment: are those extra spaces actually in there?

Comment: Try to remove spaces from href, like this: category.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>
And you sure you have something in $row['id']?

Comment: Removed extra spaces @Bushikot. But still not receiving ant value. And yeah!! $row['id'] does have value.

Comment: thank you all. it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your code from:

```
<a href = "category.php? id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo   $row['title'];?></a>
```

to:

```
<a href = "category.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo   $row['title'];?></a>
```

Remove the extra spaces before and after the id. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Osama. it working fine. newbie me!! lol

Comment: To follow up what @Osama Sayed said your extra spaces are replaced with `%20`giving you `category.php?%20id%20=%201` when you want `category.php?id=1`

Comment: @MarcBarbeau thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: @YubrajRai glad it works for you :) feel free to accept if it answers the question for you. this will result in +2 rep for you. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/321521) This signals to others that the problem is solved.